Cheap vs. expensive catalytic converters for F250
The catalytic converter on our truck got stolen and we need to get it replaced. The truck is a 2001 Ford F250 Super Duty with a V8 5.4l gasoline engine. There are very cheap universal converters out there; NAPA offers the 53033 that should be viable for that truck (according to the site) for less than a hundred bucks. There are also much more expensive universal ones. What would be the key differences compared to the cheap one, beyond a possible longer life expectancy? It's an old truck, so durability is a secondary concern. We are in Oregon, which just follows the federal exhaust standards.
To phrase the question differently: Why would anybody buy one for $400 at all? (They are not even California rated; I understand that those are more expensive.)
Or perhaps the actual question is "can I just install the cheap one, car will run fine and it will pass the DEQ inspection with it?" ;-).

Although not versed in 50 state emissions regulations, California forbids non oem catcons. New York may be second, following California. California has unique smog issues, hence tight regulations over vehicle emissions control. Another reason catcons are expensive; new vehicle warranties mandates higher quality oem catcons to avoid repeated replacement. Inexpensive catcons can meet federal/state emissions but for how long? You'll have to determine what your state's emissions regulations are and whether inexpensive catcons are allowable. If your state DMV can't help. repair shops can.

@FDryer Ah, forgot to mention Oregon. Yes, California approved ("C.A.R.B") converters are much more expensive, apparently because more precious catalyst metals are need to achieve better conversion.

Personally, unless someone corrects me, I think catcons are catcons; they're designed to convert exhaust byproducts to harmless gases. I'm not familiar with design criteria so there's a lot of latitude that may differentiate oem catcons from equal aftermarket products meeting the same criteria. As to longevity, that's solely up to aftermarket manufacturers to prove their catcons meets or exceeds oem parts. I don't know of third party reviews that do that. This is a buyer beware scenario in selecting replacement catcons.  The post catcon O2 sensor is supposed to monitor catcon efficiency.
